# Question about “Sheaves in Geometry and Logic”

Tags: category-theory

As this guy [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548837), I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 2 of Section 5, Chapter I, of MacLane-Moerdijk's "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic". Maclane proves that there is a function $Nat(P,R(E)) \rightarrow \mathcal{E}(L(P),E)$. But I can't see why It admits an inverse.

If we have a morphism $f:K \rightarrow E$ in $\mathcal{E}$, how to find a presheaf $P$ having $K$ as the colimit of $A○\pi_{p}$ in a way that reverses the Mac lane's function?